# Reading 12-bit digital value through optocoupler

Tags: circuit-design, opto-isolator

I am using an ESP32S3 to read the value of an [S9706](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3974535.pdf) color sensor.

For some reason I had to add an [optocoupler](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83654/ild621.pdf) to my schematic after the sensor output.

After uploading the code to my ESP32S3, the readings from S9706 made no sense. Without the optocoupler I can read the data successfully.

My schematic:

[image]

FS1 -> FS4 go to the ESP32S3 pins.

What can be the problem?

Oscigramms:
prior:
all bytes
[image]

one byte
[image]

After opto:
all bytes
[image]

one byte
[image]

The signal is inverted because the ouput of opto is pulluped with 10k.

Comment: _"For some reason"_ Please do explain.

Comment: The boss asked me to add the opto, for me i am not convinced.

Comment: I would find myself a new job if my manager would demand such things.

Comment: Using an optocoupler with no isolation between input and output sides is pretty useless. But to answer your question, we need more information. I.e. scope shots. It is also likely, that with this information, which is part of a standard trouble shooting, you could answer it yourself.

Comment: You may need to get an oscilloscope (2 channels + math capability would be ideal) and see why.  Try seeing what the difference is in the signal prior to and after the optocoupler.

Comment: Not sure I understand the sensor datasheet correctly, but it shows some 2 MHz clock for the read out. If you pass this through a lowpass filter with kHz cutoff, of course nothing will go through. **What is the point of the 100 nF capacitors?** But even without the lowpass, such optocouplers cannot transmit such high frequency.

Comment: @winny, you'd resign a job over a minor technical disagreement? That seems an extreme reaction to advocate/recommend: no income. Instead, OP can work through investigate the engineering problem and find its solution, which what they're doing and is great. They've come here looking to understand, progress and return with technical understanding.

Comment: @TonyM If it's a one-off, I'll let it pass, but I have a sneaking suspicion that if OPs manager does this once to flatter his/her own ego of micromanagement, it will happen again and again. I wound't stand that work situation and look for another job. The optocoupler makes no sense. Also, I'm not advocating it, I just gave my opinion how I would do in the situation.

Comment: The point of opto was only to isolate the sensor from the input of µC.
I wrote here to see if it make sense to have it or should i redesign the schematic, not to seek another job.
Anyway thanks alot to all who has replied.

Comment: The optocoupler will not isolate the sensor from the uC if they share ground. With isolated power supply for the sensor, it would.

Comment: What is the signal path between the ESP32 and the other sensor inputs FS_CLK and FS_GATE? Are there optocouplers?

Comment: @winny, afraid it reads like a big leap of guesswork and presumption of a worst stereotype but it's all off the subject anyway.

Comment: @Jens No, only the dataout of sensor is through opto to ESP32.     The FS_CLK, FS_GATE and FS_RANGE they are routed direct from ESP32 to the sensors.

Comment: There may be a reason to use optocouplers to protect the ESP32 from ESD impacts during hotplugging or other harsh environment conditions, even if GND is shared. But if this is required, it must be done for all signals or it is useless. A car is only locked if all doors are locked.

Comment: Try replacing whole opto-sensor circuit with just logic inverters, such as in a 74LVC14 IC. Make sure you put the 10K pull-ups on the inverter inputs from the sensor. Then post your findings in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate problems. All caused by adding the useless optoisolator, because it is not even used to isolate, as same ground voltage reference is used on both sides.

The data output is filtered by the RC filter, so it limits the bandwidth to about 600 Hz. The clock must be much less than than that for the data communications to work.

The sensor has a weak output. Rated to output logic levels at 0.5mA. It likely can't drive an optoisolator LED directly with enough current it needs to work properly.

Comment: Do you mean if i disclaim the LPF then it may work?

Comment: @Hamo No, I believe I mentioned the sensor output may not be able to drive the opto input with enough current, so it likely doesn't work. Also it depends on the speed as the opto outputs have 10k pull-ups. Do yourself a favor and poke the signals with an oscilloscope to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: I would search for another opto with the hope to disclaim it. Thank you.

Comment: @Hamo The sensor output is not intended to drive any other load but a digital input. Also the opto will be useless because it is not used for isolation. If you need to level shift between 5V IC and 3.3V then do that in other way. If you have ESP32 receiving the 5V, it will exceed the valid range of input voltages from the opto.

Comment: Look for a digital isolator. @Hamo And you must implement a sensor-side isolated power supply.. Or you actually question the relevance of using isolation in the first place ;)

Comment: I will look for such a digital isolator. Thank you all.